# Structure definition in C convert to VB.NET

Tags: c, vb.net

I am trying to call an unmanaged function for which I have documentation in C. I also have the C header file. It uses a large number of nested struct's that I am converting to Structure objects for VB.NET. In the callback delegate it sends a void* which I use to copy over to my Structure using Marshal.PtrToStructure. However, the result gives nearly everything as zeros so obviously I am not doing it correctly.

The structures are defined as:

```
typedef struct tagNET_TIME_EX
{
    DWORD               dwYear;                 // Year
    DWORD               dwMonth;                // Month
    DWORD               dwDay;                  // Date
    DWORD               dwHour;                 // Hour
    DWORD               dwMinute;               // Minute
    DWORD               dwSecond;               // Second
    DWORD               dwMillisecond;          // Millisecond
    DWORD               dwUTC;                  // utc query: zero means invaild, non-zero means vaild;  set:invalid
    DWORD               dwReserved[1];          // reserved data
} NET_TIME_EX,*LPNET_TIME_EX;
```

and

```
typedef struct tagDEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO
{
    int                 nChannelID;                     // ChannelId
    char                szName[128];                        // event name
    int                 nEventID;                       // event ID
    NET_TIME_EX         UTC;                            // the event happen time
    DH_MSG_OBJECT       stuObject;                      // have being detected object
   ...snip...
```

When I use the PtrToStructure, nearly everything after szName is 0.

Why is the UTC field declared as NET_TIME_EX instead of tagNET_TIME_EX? As far as I understand, the first is an instance while the second is a type. Should not the second structure be defined as:

```
typedef struct tagDEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO
{
    int                 nChannelID;                     // ChannelId
    char                szName[128];                        // event name
    int                 nEventID;                       // event ID
    tagNET_TIME_EX          UTC;                            // the event happen time
    DH_MSG_OBJECT       stuObject;                      // have being detected object
   ...snip...
```

Such types of declarations are used at multiple places and perhaps that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: First one's easy, `DWORD` in Win32 is `Integer` in .NET.  Second one is going to be more challenging.  There is an attribute you can use to identify the fixed-length string for `szName`.  I'm not certain of what you use for the contained value types for `NET_TIME_EX` and `DH_MSG_OBJECT`.

Comment: @Craig Yes, I understand DWORD, QWORD etc. well as I have a background in Assembly language programming. The NET_TIME_EX is the first structure that I gave in my question. The second structure is quite large; with all the substructures and constants that it uses, the code is over 900 lines. In my VB.NET STRUCTURE definition, I use <MarshalAs(Unmanaged.type.ByValArray, SizeConst:=128)> for the szName.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work correctly, I think there's also an option to marshal as a fixed-length string.  But it seems like the main issue is with ensuring that the embedded structures are marshaled correctly?